# SQL constraint E-Mail

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

i have an assignment that i have to do in SQL Server Manager.

I have a database, and a table named `User`. Under user there are a column named `e-mail`.

The assignment is to create a new constraint to that table that affect the column e-mail.

There has to be only one '`@`' and minimum one '`.`'

It is not allowed to be any special characters such as ( `!`, `"`, `#`, `¤`, `%`, etc.) <- this do not include the '@' and '.'

I've tried some different things but cant seem to make it work. Also it should be noticed that I am a beginner.

Thanks for your help

Comment: At least *show* your attempts. Dumping a homework question on us and expecting us to do all of the work isn't a great deal for anyone. Also be descriptive in how the attempts don't work - do they generate errors? Let you insert invalid values? Prevent insertion of valid values? Something else?

Comment: Show us your current code attempt.

Comment: Ive tried this ([e-mail] like '%_@__%.__%') 

When i try to type an email it says that it cannot be used and i have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can create your table with **constraint**, like this which will check if all the given conditions satisfies.
Please change table data with your's

**If table not Exist**

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
ID int NOT NULL,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Email  varchar(255),
CHECK (len(Email) - len(replace(Email,'@',''))=1 AND len(Email) - 
len(replace(Email,'.',''))=1 AND CHARINDEX('!',Email)!>0 AND 
CHARINDEX('#',Email)!>0 AND CHARINDEX('%',Email)!>0 AND 
CHARINDEX('¤',Email)!>0 AND CHARINDEX('"',Email)!>0)
);
```

**Some Rejected Inputs**

> some@some.!%#¤com
>
> some@some.!%#com
>
> some@some.%#com
>
> some@some.#com
>
> some@some@com
>
> !some@some@com

etc...

**Some Excepted Inputs**

> some@some.com
>
> some222@some.com
>
> harry_porter@some.com
>
> 332@some.com

etc....

**If you have already a table then**

```
 GO

 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Yourtablename]  WITH CHECK ADD Constraint EmailConstraint CHECK  (((len([Email])-
 len(replace([Email],'@','')))=(1) AND (len([Email])-
 len(replace([Email],'.','')))=(1) AND charindex('!',[Email])<=(0) AND 
 charindex('#',[Email])<=(0) AND charindex('%',[Email])<=(0) AND 
 charindex('¤',[Email])<=(0) AND charindex('"',[Email])<=(0)))
 GO
```

Comment: Hello thanks, but i do not understand any of what you wrote xD
I have to add it into the constraint, where i create a new constraint for a table, and not write it all down like that inside a query

Comment: I mean you can create your table with already have an email contraint on it uisng this method